# "Sponsoring" without implying funding

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I am trying to replace the term "sponsored" in the following context, with a better term that does not imply receiving funds or support of any kind.

> Project X was sponsored by Company Y.

Any idea?

Comment: independently developed by ?

Comment: *Promoted? Endorsed?* I think any word is likely to imply ***financial*** support in the context of a "project" and "company".

Comment: Well, I should mention that I am the developer working on Project X, but I'm not part of or funded by Company Y.

Comment: @njk: So what exactly *is* the relationship between the company and the project?

Comment: It's their project, and I'm working on it, but I'm not receiving any money or support from them.

Comment: Isn't Company Y paying someone?  Isn't someone paying you?  Or you doing this gratis, for the experience only, or on spec?

Comment: No, as I said I'm not receiving money. I'm working on it because it's the project I need to complete for my graduation.

Comment: It sounds like Project X is owned|run|managed|commissioned by Company Y

Comment: @Avon, thank you. I think that "commissioned" would work in my context. Unfortunately I cannot upvote yet.

Comment: You're welcome. In that case, I've made it into an answer.

Comment: It should be noted that "sponsoring" implies providing support of some sort -- if not money per se then facilities or materials or some such.  If no "support" of any kind is not supplied then it's not sponsorship, it's at most "endorsement".

Comment: (You really need to explain better what the relationship is between these two organizations.)

Comment: @Hot Licks, I'll try to explain again the relationship between me and the company: I am the student that is working on this project of Company Y to solve one of their problems. I'm doing this for research purposes and to complete my graduation, and without receiving any funds from the company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that "**[commissioned](https://www.google.com/search?q=commissioned%20definitio)**" would work in your context ;)

> kəˈmɪʃ(ə)n
>  verb
>  past tense: commissioned; past participle:
>   commissioned
>   1. order or authorize the production of (something).

(Google)

Comment: "Commissioned", in the US, would imply that the commissioning party somehow initiated the project -- that it didn't exist before the commissioning party's action.  The only exception to that would be if the commissioning party is some sort of umbrella tax-exempt organization, and the project operates utilizing its tax-exempt status.

Comment: @HotLicks That is the impression I'm getting from the comments from the OP: It's Company Y's project = they initiated it. Surely, they must authorize it for it to be theirs.

Answer (score 1):

Endorsed is a very very good word.

Comment: Do you mean that in the context of my sentence (an the other information that I provided in the comments) "endorsed" sounds right? Better than "commissioned"?

Comment: I'm just a common man and haven't a clue if it is better or not.  I've never seen commissioned used in such a manner.  It's just what I'd use.  I have to admit that this word doesn't preclude financial support.  -- Not that it would fit in your sentence above, but "moral" support usually means that no money is involved.

Answer (score -3):

the action to benefact is to offer aid via money or other help to a person or cause. A person who benefacts is a benefactor, a much more common version of the word.

Another definition of benefactor: one that confers a benefit; especially one that makes a gift or bequest

Comment: It seems to me that your answer is unrelated to my question.

Comment: I am sorry you think that Company Y being your benefactor, aka being your sponsor, is unrelated to them benefacting, aka sponsoring, Project X.